# Galaxy S loses wifi even though the symbol says it is connected, toggling flight mode fixes the problem

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s

There can't be anything wrong with the router because apple phones have no trouble connecting to the internet.

As I have said, the wifi symbol is active but there is no internet connection. Turning flight mode on and off again solves the issue for a little while.

I am using a galaxy s i9000 (newer phone broke, so I'll be using this for a while)

model number: GT-I9001
firmware version: 2.3.3
baseband version: I9001XXKE7
kernel version: 2.6.35.7-perf root@DELL103 #1
build number: GINGERBREAD.XXKE7

Nothing has triggered this problem as far as I know. I experienced this problem from the moment I started using the phone (about a week ago), which I freshly reverted to factory settings before using.

Comment: Who controls the Wi-Fi network? Some networks (especially corporate or academic) have a whitelist of which devices are allowed to connect, so you might need to talk to the network administrator to get this phone added to the list.

Comment: I control the wifi network. It loses connection (with the wifi symbol still showing) while it is literally placed right next to the router.